# Accessing the values of names created using metafor package metabin function for subgroup analysis

Tags: r

I have a problem accessing the random effects meta-analysis pooled effect sizes, lower, upper and I-squared values for each subgroup. See the marked values in the figure. [image]
I can see them using *summary()* or *forest()* function. But I want to export the values in excel or a data frame. I tried by accessing the names of the object created using meabin() function and printing using metabin_object$.. but it didn't work. Below is a sample data set and reproducible subgroup meta-analysis.

```
library(meta)
data("dat.bcg")
met <- metabin(tpos, tneg, cpos, cneg, data = dat.bcg,  sm="OR",
        subgroup = alloc, fixed = F,overall = F,
        studlab = paste(author, year))
forest(met, fontsize = 8)
names(met)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I simply need to print using the following code. After that, it is a matter of binding together.

```
round(met$I2.w, 2)
round(exp(met$TE.random.w), 2)
round(exp(met$lower.random.w), 2)
round(exp(met$upper.random.w), 2)
```

Comment: "*using the.*" Using the what?